# What is a more secure way for passing passwords to OpenSSL?

Tags: linux, security, environment-variables, openssl

With OpenSSL, there are two ways in bash to use an environment variable as a password:
`pass:"${var}"` and `env:var`.

I am wondering which method provides the most security, as the man page makes it seem like `ps` can read the password when passed as `pass:"${var}"`, and that it might also be possible with `env:var`.

Relevant section of the OpenSSL man page:

> ### Pass Phrase Arguments
>
> Several commands accept password arguments, typically using -passin and -passout for input and output passwords respectively. These allow the password to be obtained from a variety of sources. Both of these options take a single argument whose format is described below. If no password argument is given and a password is required then the user is prompted to enter one: this will typically be read from the current terminal with echoing turned off.
>
> #### pass:password
>
> the actual password is password. Since the password is visible to utilities (like 'ps' under Unix) this form should only be used where security is not important.
>
> #### env:var
>
> obtain the password from the environment variable var. Since the environment of other processes is visible on certain platforms (e.g. ps under certain Unix OSes) this option should be used with caution.

Answer (score 2):

The man page is pretty explicit on the matter, you should use the *env:var* method.

The man page is correct, all command line parameters are visible via ps to **all users** on the system.

```
alice$ openssl genpkey -algorithm RSA -pkeyopt rsa_keygen_bits:16384 -aes-128-cbc -pass pass:123456
```

```
evil$ ps aux|grep openssl                                                                                                                               
alice      17594  115  0.0  17108  4424 pts/6    R+   11:02   0:03 openssl genpkey -algorithm RSA -pkeyopt rsa_keygen_bits:16384 -aes-128-cbc -pass pass:123456
```

If you use an environment variable, another user (except root) will only be able to see the name of that variable but no its content.

```
alice$ OPENSSLPW=123456
alice$ openssl genpkey -algorithm RSA -pkeyopt rsa_keygen_bits:16384 -aes-128-cbc -pass env:OPENSSLPW
```

```
evil$ ps aux|grep openssl                                                                                                                               
alice      17713  115  0.0  17108  4424 pts/6    R+   11:02   0:03 openssl genpkey -algorithm RSA -pkeyopt rsa_keygen_bits:16384 -aes-128-cbc -pass env:OPENSSLPW
```

Comment: Actually, file:path is better than env:var.  ps auxwwe can display environment variables.  With file:path create the file with 400 or 600 permissions.